# Wildcard domain not working on server, give Site Unavailable message

Tags: laravel, apache, dynamic, wildcard-subdomain, directadmin

I'm building a Laravel application where each company can create their own page on a subdomain, so lets say apple.mywebsite.com. 
This all works well on my localhost.

However, when I upload it on the server the company page can't be found. 
Besides this wildcard domains, I also have 2 other subdomains as testing websites.

I already have pointed a A-record for *.mywebsite.com in the DNS to the server ip address.

Now I have setup the following in my httpd.conf:

```
|*if !SUB|
|?DOCROOT=/home/mycompany/domains/mycompany.com/public_html/public|
|*endif|
|*if SUB="b2btest"| 
|?DOCROOT=/home/mycompany/domains/mycompany.com/public_html/b2btest/public|
|*endif|
|*if SUB="staging"| 
|?DOCROOT=/home/mycompany/domains/mycompany.com/public_html/staging/public|
|*endif|
```

And my .htaccess looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mycompany.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mycompany.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mycompany.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Both the two subdomains and the main domain are working, but when I go to the wildcard subdomains they are showing me "Site is unavailable" message.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier for you to just change the virtual host of (e.g.) nginx? If you agree I have a simple solution.

Comment: That would be great! I use Apache by the way.

Comment: On which operating system is your server running? Ubuntu 18.04?